# Android getMeasuredHeight get wrong value

Tags: java, android

I have the XML like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000" >
<com.XXXXXXXXXXX.view
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

I get the view height in the method onMesure like this:

```
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    if (!isMeasured)
    {
        isMeasured = true;
        mViewHeight = getMeasuredHeight();
        mViewWidth = getMeasuredWidth();...}
```

the mViewWidth is right(600px), but the mViewHeight is wrong(1626px).
Could someone give me some pointers?
Tks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getMeasuredHeight()` will return the desired height for the child, not necessarily the height it actually gets.  You also are taking the first measured value and setting your width/height to that. `onMeasure` can be called multiple times for different reasons.  The intent is to say how much height/width your view desires with the given `MeasureSpec` constraints.  `onLayout` will get called later with where your parent actually wants you, which may not match what you asked for in `onMeasure`.

Also, views already have a `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` which are valid after the layout pass.  Do you need your own `mViewWidth` and `mViewHeight`?

Comment: I found that `heightMeasureSpec` was a negative value, the `getMeasuredHeight()` method will always get a value larger than `heightMeasureSpec`, so the method return 1626px(equals to my screen height)...tks a lot. But why the `heightMeasureSpec` is a negative value?

Comment: It's a little strange. The measure spec int contains information about the constraints imposed by the parent in the leftmost 2 bits and the remaining 30 bits are the size.  You can call MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec) to extract just the size from it.  All this does internally is widthMeasureSpec & 0x3fffffffffffffff, which is just masking out the leftmost 2 bits.  The leftmost bit indicates the size can be "at most" and the second to leftmost bit indicates exactly.  See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.MeasureSpec.html

Comment: "getMeasuredHeight() will return the desired height for the child"; then, I defined a height for the child instead of match_parent and it worked, thanks a lot!